# An invisible modification

Tags: bug

This question may require migration to Meta.SE, as it could be a site-wide "bug", but I thought that I would test the waters here, to see if there is an obvious explanation.

I noticed that a question of mine had been modified, on April 16, by "Song Khmer" <strike>in the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered), when sorted by votes</strike><sup>1</sup>:

> [image: Modification listed]

However, when checking the [revision history](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/posts/3015/revisions), the April 16 edit, by *Song Khmer*, is not shown. The last modification was the "https everywhere" edit, three days prior:

> [image: No apparent modification]

I've not noticed the behaviour before. What is going on? Is it a bug, or something really obvious that I can't see?

Was it a rejected edit? If the latter, then should it really be shown in the Unanswered question list? Shouldn't the modifications listed in the Unanswered questions list, actually only be accepted modifications/edits?

---

<sup>1</sup> The unanswered list, and the sorting, are irrelevant to the actual issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the "invisible modification", there is technically a modification made multiple times by the user **Song Khmer** (now destroyed). This user was posting nonsense to your question by copying text from your question and posting it as an answer.

The reason you probably did not see this in the revision history is:

1) it wasn't a direct edit to your question

2) I believe only moderators can see deleted posts.

[image] [click here for full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VAiL.png) of deleted posts

I'm pretty sure that anytime someone posts an answer or edits your question, the post raises the modified flag. In this case, when the user was posting answers it would properly flag the post. But, the flag remained even after the answers were deleted (there were 3 answers).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Mystery solved. :-) However, what is very weird is that the reason I did not see those changes was that I was stuck in Cambodia for three weeks, with no internet access, at around that time... and *Khmer* is a dialect of that region... Hmmm...

Comment: That is interesting, and a bit suspicious lol Might be a good time to double check your passwords...

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Exchange network is undergoing a transition to HTTPS for its sites, including 3D Printing SE.

This edit (from Community, it looks like), was probably scripted from SE Staff in attempt to fix content on Questions and Answers. Ultimately, I don't think this is worth migrating the SE Meta.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't particularly clear on my query. The point that I am trying to make is that a modification is shown as being made by "Song Khmer", when the question is listed in the unanswered list (I know *why* it is in the unanswered list - because it hasn't got an answer... :-) ). However, the modification by "Song Khmer" doesn't show up in the list of edits... so my question is, why does it say that it was modified by "Song Khmer" when in fact it wasn't..? This seems to me to be a site-wide bug, as it probably isn't only restricted to SE 3D Printing.

Comment: I have modified the question, to try to clarify the issue

Comment: Is it now too late to migrate this question to SE.Meta? If so, could you notify me, that it is too late, in a comment, and I'll close/delete the question and repost on SE Meta. It is clearly a site-wide bug, and I'll report it as such, but I want to avoid cross-posting it.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. I didn't receive a notification about your post until this morning. See my second answer down below for more clarification on your situation.